# Java Selection Sort returning repeated values

Tags: java, sorting

```
int [] arr2 = {43, 56, 44, 56, 21, 75, 41};

int max = arr2[0];
int temp3 = 0;
int tempLoc = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length - 1; i++){
    for(int j=arr2.length-1; j < 1; j--){
        if(arr2[j-1] < arr2[j] ){
            max=arr2[j];
            tempLoc = j;
        } else{

            max = arr2[j-1];
            tempLoc = j;
        }

    }

    //replace elements here.
    temp3 = arr2[arr2.length - 1 - i];
    arr2[arr2.length - 1 - i] = max;
    arr2[tempLoc] = temp3;

}

System.out.println("\n " + Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

I have this, and the output is:

```
{56 43 43 43 43 43 43}
```

I do not want a solution per say, I would like for someone to help me find the problem. To me it goes like this:

(1) Eg with i=1, in the j-loop, the maximum is being found then the loop ends Then the elements are replaced properly I'd say?

So what is the issue?

Comment: Did you mean for your inner loop to run while `j > 1` instead of `j < 1` perhaps?

Comment: Run the code under debugger and you can see for yourself every step of the way. No guessing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , sorry about that, its been updated

Comment: @PM77-1, how does one see that in IntelliJ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: @PM77-1, I have read through and watched videos but it doesnt show the type of debugging for showing steps?

Comment: @PM77-1, I debugged it, the max value never changes and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, in second loop you have `j < 1`, there should be `j > 1` or maybe `j > 0` (not sure, your algorithm).

Second, you are assigning max no matter what, you should check if current max is bigger than what you want to assign, if it is then leave it alone. Also you are always assigning `tempLoc`to `j`, don't know what that's about. Generally I think that your finding max is too complicated, just go through all elements and assign values to max if they are bigger, and remember the index, like this:

```java
for(int j=0; j<arr2.length-i; j++){
  if(arr2[j] > max){
    max = arr2[j];
    indexOfMax = j;
  }
}
```

But like I said, it's your algorithm, you may want to do something different.

Comment: I debugged it. The problem the max stays what it is defined at all times. So the max is never changing for some odd reason?

Comment: Use my version, and at the end of the outer for set `max` to `0` and `indexOfMax` to `0`, and do `arr2[indexOfMax] = temp3;` instead of `arr2[tempLoc] = temp3;`, it will work. I wrote it all at home and tested it and it worked, if you can't figure it out then write it, when I come home I will post the solution.